# Difference between HikariCP 2.4.3 (latest release) and release version 2.3.8?

Tags: database, jdbc, hikaricp

I would appreciate if someone could answer what the major differences are between the aforementioned versions of HikariCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually performed an update on one application a couple of days ago from 2.3.9 to 2.4 so here are some of the features that you can enjoy in the 2.4.3 release:

- Fixed race condition when creating an rapidly ramping connections in the pool (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/452)
- Improve pool shutdown behavior.  Stop active connection acquisition once the shutdown sequence has initiated. - *Personally I think this one is really important and was one of the reasons for our upgrade*
- Stop closing idle connections, to keep `minimumIdle` connections in pool (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/379)
- Java 6 support is now in maintenance mode
- Deprecated `HikariDataSource.shutdown()` in favor of `close()`
- Performance improvements (incl. reduced garbage generation)

This list is by no means exhaustive. The question is somewhat broad so I listed items that are important from my point of view and I have experience with. If you are looking for something concrete, you are welcome to ask another question of browse through the release notes yourself:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/CHANGES

Comment: Thanks. Really useful for me.

Question: About the first point (Race condition), I wonder when at what version/release is that introduced?